# How to move smoothly a character in Javascript (without Canvas)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm kinda struggling to animate a character in a js game i'm currently trying to develop. I can't use canvas so it's only DIVs. With the current functions, i can move my character left / right but it's not smooth at all, it's kind of "step by step". I've been looking for answers but the only solutions i've found uses canvas.

Here's my code (works better in fullscreen but kinda glitched with positions) :

```js
function avancerRight()
{
 var batman=document.getElementById("batman");
 x=batman.style.left;
 
  batman.className="dirDroite";
  batman.style.left=parseInt(x)+10+"px";

 return false;
}

function avancerLeft()
{
 console.log("dedede");
 var batman=document.getElementById("batman");
 x=batman.style.left;
 
  batman.className="dirGauche";
  batman.style.left=parseInt(x)-10+"px";

 return false;
}



var jumpHeight = 200;
var jumping = false;
function jump() {
                        
  if (!jumping) {
    jumping = true;
    setTimeout(land, 500);
  }

  if (jumping) {
    y=batman.style.top;

  batman.style.top=parseInt(y)-jumpHeight+"px";
  }
}

function land()
{
 jumping=false;

 y=batman.style.top;

 batman.style.top=parseInt(y)+jumpHeight+"px";
}
```

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: url('http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/16/1428996568-bg.png');
 background-color: #B4381F;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: 50% 30%; 

}

#batman{
 background-image:url('http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/16/1428996568-batman.png');
 width:85px;
 height:85px;
 display:block;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 position:absolute;
 margin-top: -80px;
}

.dirDroite{
 background-position: -95px 0px;
}

.dirGauche{
 background-position: 0px 0px;
}

#fullbody {
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#floor {
 position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
 background: url("http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/16/1428996568-platform5.png");
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 height: 126px;
 
}

#base {
 position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 80px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 200;
 margin: auto;
 background: url('http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/16/1428996568-thefloor.png');
 background-size: cover;
 height: 70.56px;
 width: 846.72px;
 margin-top : 13.2vh;
}



#perspectiveGauche{
 margin-top : 15vh;
 -webkit-perspective: 4vh;
    perspective: 4vh;
    position: absolute;
    width: 45vw;
    perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
}

#rectangleHautGaucheH{
 margin-left: 13.22vh;
 width: 28.87vw;
 height: 2vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
}

#rectangleBasGaucheH{
 width: 29.1vw;
 margin-left: 13vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

#perspectiveGaucheBasse{
 margin-top : 15vh;
 -webkit-perspective: 0.1vh;
    perspective: 0.1vw;
    position: absolute;
    width: 45vw;
    perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
}

#rectangleHautGaucheB{
 margin-top: 38vh;
 margin-left: 28vh;
 width: 15vw;
 height: 0.25vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
}

#rectangleBasGaucheB{
 margin-top: 0.6vh;
 width: 15.25vw;
 margin-left: 27.75vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

#perspectiveDroite{
 -webkit-perspective: 4vh;
    perspective: 4wh;
    position: absolute;
    width: 39.6vw;
    height: 2vh;
    margin-top: 15vh;
    perspective-origin: 200% 0%;
}

#rectangleHautDroitH{
 margin-left: 125vh;
 width: 28.7vw;
 height: 2vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
}

#rectangleBasDroitH{
 width: 28.9vw;
 margin-left: 124.8vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

#rectangleHautDroiteB{
 margin-top: 37vh;
 margin-left: 133vh;
 width: 22vw;
 height: 2vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
}

#rectangleBasDroiteB{
 margin-top: 0.2vh;
 width: 22.18vw;
 margin-left: 132.8vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

#perspectiveMilieu{
 -webkit-perspective: 4vh;
    perspective: 4wh;
    position: absolute;
    width: 39.6vw;
    height: 2vh;
    margin-top: 15vh;
    perspective-origin: 130% 0%;
 
}

#rectangleHautMilieu{
 margin-top: 21vh;
 margin-left: 68.95vh;
 width: 34.5vw;
 height: 2vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
    
}

#rectangleBasMilieu{
 margin-top: 0.1vh;
 width: 34.77vw;
 margin-left: 68.7vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>LEVEL 1 NEGRILLON</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/script.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="fullbody">

 <div id="perspectiveGauche">
  <div id="rectangleHautGaucheH"></div>
  <div id="rectangleBasGaucheH"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="perspectiveGaucheBasse">
  <div id="rectangleHautGaucheB"></div>
  <div id="rectangleBasGaucheB"></div>
 </div>

  <div id="perspectiveDroite">
   <div id="rectangleHautDroitH"></div>
   <div id="rectangleBasDroitH"></div>
   <div id="rectangleHautDroiteB"></div>
   <div id="rectangleBasDroiteB"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="perspectiveMilieu">
   <div id="rectangleHautMilieu"></div>
   <div id="rectangleBasMilieu"></div>
  </div>

 
  <div id="base"></div>
  
  <div id="floor"></div>
  
  <!--<div id="platform1"></div>
   
  <div id="platform5"></div>
  <div id="floor">-->

 <div id="batman" class="dirDroite" style="left:700px;top:280px;"></div>
 <div id="zone" style="left:300px;top:50px;"></div>

 


  <script>
  document.onkeydown = pave;
  function pave(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      if (e.keyCode == '38') {
          jump();
      }
      else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
          avancerBottom();
      }
      else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
          avancerLeft();
      }
      else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
          avancerRight();
      }
  }

 </script>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Also, i'm trying to implement a jump action, if you have any ideas to make the whole movement instead of just a 'teleportation', i'll appreciate it.

Thanks guys !
Cheers.

Comment: I would also want a good answer to that , till than can you use css animations?

Comment: I don't think so since i need to use keycodes elements (the games uses the keyboard). From now we are applying margins to the css #batman with js.

Comment: then use transitions? transitions get applied on elements like , #batman { transition : margin 1s , background-color 2s; } try them :)

Comment: can you post that code on jsfiddle editing suitably ? I would love to make it work and play with it. I am certain using css would be sufficient in this case or a little bit of js :D

Comment: sure thing @AbhinavGauniyal, here is a codepen of it, make it fullscreen : http://codepen.io/PaulBorensztein/pen/PwMGYO also, i made a few changes now the animation is fluid but i can't stop it, if you have any ideas on how to fix it, would be nice !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so i basically made it throught with this simple script :

```
setInterval(bougerPerso, 10);
var touche = {}
var avancer = 8;

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    touche[e.keyCode] = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    delete touche[e.keyCode];
});


function bougerPerso() {
    for (var direction in touche) {
        if (direction == 37){
            $("#batman").animate({left: "-=5"}, 0); // Met l'id de ta div qui doit bouger ici!             
        }

        if (direction == 39) {
            $("#batman").animate({left: "+=5"}, 0); // Met l'id de ta div qui doit bouger ici! 
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks every one for helping me, here is the working code : 
http://codepen.io/PaulBorensztein/pen/PwMGYO

Now i'm looking to make realistic jumps, any ideas on the process to do it ?

Comment: Ok I just tried jumping and landing on the same place where it started.. and as of now if you start jumping from the position where it was at the beginning, how many times ever you press up arrow mark it will land at the same position where it was at the begining + if you press up and simultaneously left/right, you can see movements to its left/right. check my **[Code link](https://jsfiddle.net/gnuLwj7d/26/)** and **[this demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/gnuLwj7d/26/embedded/result/)**. Not that great movements but still some handful of ideas you might get.

Comment: + visit  **[this link](http://digipiph.com/blog/creating-sprite-character-movement-javascript-and-jquery-ver-10)**

Answer (score 3):

Had to do couple of tweaks!

http://codepen.io/smartsendy34/pen/emqdEm

Right movement is smoother now!

// USING JAVASCRIPT

```
var moveKey = 0;
var moveTime = 0 ;
var frames = 10;
var second = 50;
var fps = second/frames;

function avancerRight()
{
    var batman=document.getElementById("batman");
    x=parseInt(batman.style.left);

    batman.className="dirDroite";

    clearTimeout(moveTime);
        moveTime = setTimeout(function(){
        clearInterval(moveKey);
    },second);        

    clearInterval(moveKey);
    moveKey = setInterval(function(){
        x = x+(10 / frames);
        batman.style.left = x + "px";      
    },fps);

    return false;
}
```

// USING JQUERY

```
function avancerRight()
{
    var batman=document.getElementById("batman");
     x=batman.style.left;

    batman.className="dirDroite";
    $(batman).stop().animate({"left":(x+10)},100);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Need to clear intervals before creating new interval, so that it don't go into multiple loops. Same thing happens with jQuery Stop(), before animate. It clears the animation queue.

Comment: I agree.. forgot to mention that.. :) Nice work though.. :) +1 for that.. :)

Comment: I have the same result out here, can't stop it thought, any ideas why ? 
http://codepen.io/PaulBorensztein/pen/PwMGYO

Comment: @PaulBorensztein. You cannot stop it because you are using `setInterval` which will keep on running for every specified time..

Comment: @PaulBorensztein edited the answer. Javascript version. Need to add a clearTimeout, to clear the interval loop after one second.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have tagged `jquery` I would suggest you to use `jquery animate` and I've tried something like below which gives a smooth movement but to make it perfect you need work little bit on that. You can also include `jquery-easing.js` and do more perfect operations on animations. Give a try. Same stands for your jump and drop. `animate` will help you in the said scenarios.

```js
function avancerRight()
{
 var batman=document.getElementById("batman");
 x=batman.style.left;
 
 batman.className="dirDroite";
        $(batman)..stop().animate({left: parseInt(x)+10+'px'}); //this change
 //batman.style.left=parseInt(x)+10+"px";

 return false;
}

function avancerLeft()
{
 console.log("dedede");
 var batman=document.getElementById("batman");
 x=batman.style.left;
 
        batman.className="dirGauche"; 
        $(batman).stop().animate({left: parseInt(x)-10+'px'});//this change
 //batman.style.left=parseInt(x)-10+"px";

 return false;
}
var jumpHeight = 200;
var jumping = false;
function jump() {
                        
  if (!jumping) {
    jumping = true;
    setTimeout(land, 500);
  }

  if (jumping) {
    y=batman.style.top;

  batman.style.top=parseInt(y)-jumpHeight+"px";
  }
}

function land()
{
 jumping=false;

 y=batman.style.top;

 batman.style.top=parseInt(y)+jumpHeight+"px";
}
```

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: url('http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/16/1428996568-bg.png');
 background-color: #B4381F;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: 50% 30%; 

}

#batman{
 background-image:url('http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/16/1428996568-batman.png');
 width:85px;
 height:85px;
 display:block;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 position:absolute;
 margin-top: -80px;
}

.dirDroite{
 background-position: -95px 0px;
}

.dirGauche{
 background-position: 0px 0px;
}

#fullbody {
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#floor {
 position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
 background: url("http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/16/1428996568-platform5.png");
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 height: 126px;
 
}

#base {
 position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 80px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 200;
 margin: auto;
 background: url('http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/16/1428996568-thefloor.png');
 background-size: cover;
 height: 70.56px;
 width: 846.72px;
 margin-top : 13.2vh;
}



#perspectiveGauche{
 margin-top : 15vh;
 -webkit-perspective: 4vh;
    perspective: 4vh;
    position: absolute;
    width: 45vw;
    perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
}

#rectangleHautGaucheH{
 margin-left: 13.22vh;
 width: 28.87vw;
 height: 2vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
}

#rectangleBasGaucheH{
 width: 29.1vw;
 margin-left: 13vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

#perspectiveGaucheBasse{
 margin-top : 15vh;
 -webkit-perspective: 0.1vh;
    perspective: 0.1vw;
    position: absolute;
    width: 45vw;
    perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
}

#rectangleHautGaucheB{
 margin-top: 38vh;
 margin-left: 28vh;
 width: 15vw;
 height: 0.25vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
}

#rectangleBasGaucheB{
 margin-top: 0.6vh;
 width: 15.25vw;
 margin-left: 27.75vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

#perspectiveDroite{
 -webkit-perspective: 4vh;
    perspective: 4wh;
    position: absolute;
    width: 39.6vw;
    height: 2vh;
    margin-top: 15vh;
    perspective-origin: 200% 0%;
}

#rectangleHautDroitH{
 margin-left: 125vh;
 width: 28.7vw;
 height: 2vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
}

#rectangleBasDroitH{
 width: 28.9vw;
 margin-left: 124.8vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

#rectangleHautDroiteB{
 margin-top: 37vh;
 margin-left: 133vh;
 width: 22vw;
 height: 2vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
}

#rectangleBasDroiteB{
 margin-top: 0.2vh;
 width: 22.18vw;
 margin-left: 132.8vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

#perspectiveMilieu{
 -webkit-perspective: 4vh;
    perspective: 4wh;
    position: absolute;
    width: 39.6vw;
    height: 2vh;
    margin-top: 15vh;
    perspective-origin: 130% 0%;
 
}

#rectangleHautMilieu{
 margin-top: 21vh;
 margin-left: 68.95vh;
 width: 34.5vw;
 height: 2vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
    
}

#rectangleBasMilieu{
 margin-top: 0.1vh;
 width: 34.77vw;
 margin-left: 68.7vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>LEVEL 1 NEGRILLON</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/script.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="fullbody">

 <div id="perspectiveGauche">
  <div id="rectangleHautGaucheH"></div>
  <div id="rectangleBasGaucheH"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="perspectiveGaucheBasse">
  <div id="rectangleHautGaucheB"></div>
  <div id="rectangleBasGaucheB"></div>
 </div>

  <div id="perspectiveDroite">
   <div id="rectangleHautDroitH"></div>
   <div id="rectangleBasDroitH"></div>
   <div id="rectangleHautDroiteB"></div>
   <div id="rectangleBasDroiteB"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="perspectiveMilieu">
   <div id="rectangleHautMilieu"></div>
   <div id="rectangleBasMilieu"></div>
  </div>

 
  <div id="base"></div>
  
  <div id="floor"></div>
  
  <!--<div id="platform1"></div>
   
  <div id="platform5"></div>
  <div id="floor">-->

 <div id="batman" class="dirDroite" style="left:700px;top:280px;"></div>
 <div id="zone" style="left:300px;top:50px;"></div>

 


  <script>
  document.onkeydown = pave;
  function pave(e) {
      e = e || window.event;
      if (e.keyCode == '38') {
          jump();
      }
      else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
          avancerBottom();
      }
      else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
          avancerLeft();
      }
      else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
          avancerRight();
      }
  }

 </script>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yea, I agree @Abhinav. I just gave an idea. To make it work perfectly its a hell outa work.. :)

Comment: As @Sandeep said you might need to use `.stop` before `.animate` to work without lagging.. :)

Comment: Okay i tried this @GuruprasadRao, here is my code :
`function avancerRight() {
 
 x=batman.position().left;
 batman.animate({left:x+50+'px'},100);
 console.log(x);
 batman.addClass( "dirDroite" );
  // batman.style.left=parseInt(x)+10+"px";
  // console.log('ok');
 return false;
 
}

$('#fullbody').on('keyup',function(){
 batman.stop();
});`

But it's not really super-smooth, any idea on how to improve it ?

Comment: Just have some doubt. you `avancerRight` function is bit difficult to read.. You have commented some part and kept some part. So please remove whatever you have commented so that I can check it on..

Comment: **[See this Link](https://jsfiddle.net/gnuLwj7d/9/embedded/result/)** Let me know what you are expecting by saying `super-smooth`?

Comment: `function avancerLeft()
{
 var batmanp=document.getElementById("batman");
 x=batman.position().left;
 batman.animate({left:x-50+'px'},100);
 console.log(x);
 batmanp.className="dirGauche";
 return false;
}`

`$('#fullbody').on('keyup',function(){
 batman.stop();
});`

Here you go. By super-smooth i mean, a very fluid animation and when you stop pressing the key, it immediately stops moving

Comment: Did you check my previous comment. I have given a link. You need more smoother than that?? then you might need to include one more js file called **[jquery Easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)**

Comment: Hey @GuruprasadRao , thanks for the links ! I finally did it, check my Answer above with the code :)

Comment: Thanks buddy ! (now it's time for the jump, struggling to make my character jump and move at the same time, if you have any ideas i'll take) :)